# SharePoint Content Databases with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, central-administration, content-database

Is there a way to get the current maximun number of site collections from a current database, and then be able to increase this by 1. I want to do this specifically in PowerShell for SharePoint.

Thanks

Comment: I got the answer, it is below. I mean maximum as in the field "maximum number of site collections" from the central admin SharePoint site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
get-spcontentdatabase | select name, maximumsitecount
```

or if you want that value specifically, and you know the name, you can do

```
$db = get-spcontentdatabase databaseName
$db.MaximumSiteCount
```

that should return names and maximum site count. Then to set it

```
set-spcontentdatabase databaseName -maxsitecount 100
```

Comment: Would that be setting the max site count to 100?

Comment: Yes, that 100 is the value to set to

Comment: Think it is possible to set the max site count for a content database to a varible. Then replace where you had '100' with that varible +1 ?

Comment: absolutely! you can do `$maxSite = $db.MaximumSiteCount` then increment it and use that instead